# Why does it even compile? - Compile and run native method from java using swig generated classes

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, swig

So I have followed [this](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) Swig tutorial to generate JNI proxy class and shared library. In result I have got libexmple.so file.

In **Building a Java module** tutorial section you can see.

```
 $ swig -java example.i
 $ gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I/c/jdk1.3.1/include -I/c/jdk1.3.1/include/win32
 $ gcc -shared example.o  example_wrap.o -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias  -o example.dll
 $ cat main.java

 public class main {
       public static void main(String argv[]) {
         System.loadLibrary("example");
         System.out.println(example.getMy_variable());
         System.out.println(example.fact(5));
         System.out.println(example.get_time());
       }
 }

 $ javac main.java
 $ java main
 3.0
 120
 Mon Mar  4 18:20:31  2002
```

3.0, 120 and Mon Mar  4 18:20:31  2002 are functions results.

Honestly I didnt even expected it to compile, but it did and **it runs without problem** when i do java main.
**So my 1 question is? How does java know what "example" is in println method call**

```
System.out.println(example.getMy_variable());
```

when I try to compile it thourgh Intellij IDE, naturaly it throws me an error 
"could not find symbol example" as i should throw.

**2ndly when i try to use this library in this way**

```
public class Main {

static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("example");
        System.out.println("lib initialized");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

public static native void My_variable_set(double jarg1);

public static native double My_variable_get();

public static native int fact(int jarg1);

public static native int my_mod(int jarg1, int jarg2);

public static native String get_time();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Main.fact(3);
        System.out.println("method called successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.Main.fact(I)I
```

when trying to call native method.

I am sure that lib is loaded properly (getting lib initialized log). When I tried to load non existence i got different error (class load exception)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no exampleld in java.library.path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why does it even compile?*

Because **javac** can see that **main** uses class **example** from the same *package*, and compiles it. Actually, it finds also the class **exampleJNI**, which is also auto-generated by **swig**, and is used in **example.java**.

*How does java know what "example" is in println method call?*

In Java, you don't need **`import`** for classes that are in the same package, that's how **java** knows to call **example.getMy_variable()**.

*when i try to use this library, I get exception*

Your attempt to move the native methods from **exampleJNI.java** to **main.java** failed because with JNI, the name of the class is used to determine the name of the native function. You can see it if you look at the list of exported functions of **example.dll**.

If you want to use **swig**, just use the files it generated. If you want to understand better how JNI works, read the books or online documents, follow tutorials, etc. Don't try to use **swig** for what it is not: an introduction to JNI programming.